# Android Google Sign In is flashing a small empty white box while signing in a user

Tags: android, progressdialog, google-signin

Basically, Android **Google Sign In is flashing a small empty white box** after the user presses the sign in button and before Google finishes the sign in process.  This all happens pretty fast but I would like to get rid of the white box.  I assume this white box is a failed attempt to show a progress bar.

Edit:  Adding a graphical recreation of what is happening...

[image: Representation]

**I'm testing on Samsung Tab 3.**

This problem does not include the situation where the user is signing in for the first time or after access has been revoked.

```
  GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
      .requestEmail()
      .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.google_server_client_id))
      .build();

  // google login stuff
  googlebutton = (com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.googlebutton);
  googlebutton.setOnClickListener(this);
  googlebutton.setStyle(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD, SignInButton.COLOR_LIGHT);
  // Build GoogleApiClient with access to basic profile
  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
      .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
      .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
      .build();
```

and the sign in function...

```
private void gSignIn() {
  Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
  startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

Ideally, I would like to restore the normal progress bar behaviour.

Here is my gradle...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Can you post a picture of it in action by any chance?

Comment: It happens too fast for me to get a screenshot.  The box is about as big as two word sentence.  It really is just a small white box.  Not pixel tiny, but word small.

Comment: I added an image, a simulated recreation of the white box.

Comment: did you get solution for this

Comment: @sector11 no I never found a solution

Comment: did anybody get solution for this...

Comment: Did anyone ?  in recent apps i have seen they have found a workaround for this.  I'm having this issue for more than five months

Comment: Did anyone find the solution yet?

Comment: have you add a proper SHA1 key and did you compile this build from the same machine who's SHA1 key you add in the console

Comment: Can you share the layout ?

Comment: @deanresin try updating to `11.8.0` ...and only instance the client once.

Comment: You are using a relatively old gms version, try updating to the latest one

Answer (score 1):

Try this not sure:
It is nothing but just a label you have applied to that activity in manifest, 
remove this from that activity

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

OR check you layout file does there exist some empty view which is getting visible.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i think you haven't add

#### apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

outside the dependency section.
also add classpath in project level gradle file

#### classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

update the google play services ,Android platform tools and android build tools.
sometimes it happens due to the version conflict
try this,but i'm not sure about this

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have used Button view in XML and then you are casting to com.google...SignInButton , due to his empty box is shown for while. Try changing XML view to **com.google...SignInButton**  .